# Updating MySQL boolean (tinyint) value from php

Tags: php, mysql

I have a bit of a problem with a script I'm writing.

```
$sql ="UPDATE users SET adagio = 1 WHERE username = '$_SESSION[username]'";
```

The main problem here is that, while I've tested that

1. this part of the code will run
2. I've successfully connected to the correct server

3) `$_SESSION[username]` gives me the the correct username,
the database isn't updated when I run the code. adagio is a boolean (well, a tinybit, really), and I've uploaded my phpMyAdmin screen of the database here:

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yer2T.jpg)

I'm not entirely sure why it isn't working, and although I've searched online and found similar threads, there wasn't a fix in any thread that worked for me. I'm wondering if one of you could possibly see what I'm doing wrong here?

Edit extra:

```
if(($_POST['adagio']) == 1){
$sql ="UPDATE users SET adagio = 1 WHERE username = '$_SESSION[username]'";
}
```

Comment: What database extension are you using; *mysql*, *mysqli* or *PDO*? Can you show some more code around how you're executing the query?

Comment: @Phil I'm using mysql 5.1. I've updated the original post with some more of the code. (it's quite short, that's all there is right now, besides my code connecting be to the database and session_start) Basically, I'm getting a result from a checkbox (0 or 1), and then, if it's one, enabling adagio in the database.

Comment: Please read my question again, **carefully**. How do you **execute** the query? There will be a line of code that **executes** the query in `$sql`. **Show that line**

Answer (score 2):

`$_SESSION[username]` is almost certainly a string so it must be in quotes:

```
$sql ="UPDATE users SET adagio = 1 WHERE username = '$_SESSION[username]'";
```

FYI, MySQL would be happy to tell you about SQL errors if you check for them. You should be using the appropriate error reporting functions in whatever MySQL library you are using.

Comment: Why did this answer get downvotes?

Comment: @castis here's the relevant manual entry - http://php.net/manual/language.types.string.php#example-93. See the *koolaid1* part

Comment: +1 because *`"MySQL would be happy to tell you about SQL errors if you check for them"`*

Comment: @JohnConde Thanks for the advice, I edited the original post. I tried this before, and since it didn't work, I changed it back- but it is a string, so it's better to keep it that way, I guess. I've tried it again with quotes, but it still won't affect the database. I'm starting to think that this is a MySQL problem, but I just wanted to make sure that my code was correct. (I didn't downvote, I don't have enough rep)

Comment: Echo out your query and post it here. That will show whether it is a SQL error  or not.

Comment: @JohnConde I'm getting the following result: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING

Comment: Something else is wrong besides that query.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this.

```
if (1 == $_POST['adagio']) {
    $sql = sprintf ( "UPDATE users SET adagio = 1 WHERE username = '%s'", mysql_escape_string($_SESSION['username']) );
}
```

Comment: Care to explain how this resolves their issue?

Comment: Although you seem to be worried about the SQL syntax, my belief is that, `$_POST['adagio']` is not getting proper value. The SQL syntax seems fine with me. You can manually try from SQL command line or something like phpmyadmin. You're checking if $_POST['adagio'] has value, then update the row in the table. I'm think it should be if $_POST['adagio'] is 1 then update the row in the table.